# Binary search in sequential data without repetitions

Tags: algorithm, sorting, binary-search

I'm considering the following problem,

Given a sorted array of size n containing integers without duplicates, can we do better than a normal binary search using the property that

- a) there are no duplicates
- b) there are no integers between two adjacent integers (i.e. after 50 either there is 51 or 51 is not in the array)

The idea is that when you meet a value, you add a test to see if the value you seek is adjacent to current value (+ or -1), if so, the search interval instead of being halved is reduced to a single point, the index next to current mid.

For instance, suppose you have an array tab[i]=i for all index and with all values from 0 to 99. We look for 51, the first mid is 50, so a normal binary search is in for a worst case scenario in 7 hits (log2 (100)). With the additional test, we test 50, and reduce the search interval to the neighbor of 50, so finish in two steps (but with an added test).

This is one example but is not representative of my data set, another example could be {0,13223,13225,42341,42342} or any set of values sorted without repeats. Just to give some context, these arrays I'm manipulating  are the keys (non empty indices) in a Sparse array implementation.

In the worst case, it seems that we conclude when the interval is size 3 instead of 2, so log2(n)-1 tests.

In code this would give something like (Java used here) invoke with 0 as lo and length of array-1  as hi to search the whole array:

```
// This is Arrays.binarySearch(), but doesn't do any argument validation.
    static int binarySearchGT(int[] array, int value, int lo, int hi) {
        while (lo <= hi) {
            final int mid = (lo + hi) >>> 1;
            final int midVal = array[mid];
            if (midVal < value) {
                lo = mid + 1;
            } else if (midVal > value) {
                hi = mid - 1;
            } else {
                return mid;  // value found
            }
        }
        return ~lo;  // value not present
    }
```

becomes

```
    static int binarySearch(int[] array, int value, int lo, int hi) {
        while (lo <= hi) {
            final int mid = (lo + hi) >>> 1;
            final int midVal = array[mid];
            if (midVal < value) {
                if (hi != mid && midVal == value -1) {
                    hi = mid + 1;
                } 
                lo = mid + 1;
            } else if (midVal > value) {
                if (lo != mid && midVal == value + 1) {
                    lo = mid - 1;                       
                }
                hi = mid - 1;
            } else {
                return mid;  // value found
            }
        }
        return ~lo;  // value not present
    }
```

Is my reasoning correct in thinking that this should (always) be better than the normal binary search in this particular discrete/non repeating case of inputs ? I do see that I have an additional branch and two boolean tests including an addition, but still with large inputs, can you exhibit a case where this strategy is clearly worst ?

Does anyone know of a reference to some kind of similar idea in the literature ?

[Edited to better explain not all elements are present]

Comment: Your worst case is actually worse here. I'll elaborate why below.

Comment: I feel like I am missing something here. If your data are integers, sorted and sequential, can't you just look at the first element and adjust the index? If you have an array of all integers [0 .... 100], and if you are looking for 50, well it will always be at the 50th index. If you have an array [50....100] and you are looking for 75, you know it will be at 75-51 = 24th index. Wouldn't this give you constant time always? Maybe I am understanding wrong or not seeing the purpose of searching sequential data

Comment: @sinanspd Yeah, a jump table is always best for sequential or transformed-into-sequential data.

Comment: What did you mean by "there are no integers between two adjacent integers"?  Your example doesn't seem to satisfy this.

Comment: edited question to answer @ScottHunter this is not like in reals where there are any number of values between two reals, so no proper notion of adjacent

Comment: (b) is a consequence of it being sorted integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you cannot guarantee that there will be a value in the array adjacent to what is searched for, *in the worst case* there isn't, meaning the cost is the same as a binary search.  Worse, actually, because you have added an extra test for every element you inspect.

Comment: You can guarantee it, but only at the last 2 elements in the recursion. Which means you double the tests for 1 less recursion depth. IE, not worth it.

Comment: ok so this suggests my worst case could be an array with no adjacent entries [0,2,4,6...] fits. Ok yes I can see this happening.

Answer (score 1):

So, binary searches: the reason why we get `~log2(n)` searches for a given sequence is because we split the sequence into 2 groups on every recursion, so we bottom out at a tree depth of log2(n). Say, we have the ordered numbers sequence [0,63] as a set, then our splits to find 39 look as follows:

## Normal Binary Search

```
value = 39
Step 1: [0,63], split at 32
Step 2: [32-63], split at 48
Step 3: [32-47], split at 40
Step 4: [32-39], split at 36
Step 5: [36-39], split at 38
Step 6: [38-39], split at 39
Step 7: Found 39
```

## Your Algorithm

```
value = 39
Step 1: [0,63], split at 32
Step 2: [32-63], split at 48
Step 3: [32-47], split at 40
Step 4: [32-39], split at 36
Step 5: [36-39], split at 38
Step 6: Found 39
```

As you can see, all we've done is lower the maximum depth of the tree by 1, in the worse-case scenario, but we've increased the number of tests per depth 2-fold. Your algorithm requires 12 tests to find the value, while the traditional binary search only requires 7. Ultimately, the time complexity is the still `O(log(n))`, but the coefficients are worse. In every situation, the worst-case performance is worse here than a traditional binary search.

The issue here is you've assumed the **worst-case** scenario for **binary searches** are still the **worst-case** scenario for your algorithm, when in-fact it's a **best-case** scenario for your algorithm.

Comment: Actually, my algorithm at stops at step 3' : we test 40 =39+1 and step 4 range is [39-39]

Comment: but yes, a counter-example like this is pretty much what I was hoping for as an answer, but they are hard to construct.

Comment: I forgot the +/-1, but yes, then it's another set of tests per loop, and the conditions would change slightly.